# Table Join returns Null with matching fields in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, nvarchar

I have a weird problem. I'm trying to run this code but it keeps returning no matches. This should work. The LanguageId exists in both tables. The only thing I can think of is that there is the field type is nvarchar.

```
SELECT Users.LanguageId
FROM Users
JOIN Locale ON Users.LanguageId = Locale.LanguageId
```

You can download the test database at http://www.mediafire.com/download/3eute31s35tygw2/TEST.zip. I'm guessing there is something with the way the 'en-us' is saved to Users.LanguageId. If delete the value and manually type in 'en-us' then it works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and show the declarations of the `LanguageId` column in the two tables.  You can also set up an example on SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LanguageId on one table is en-us and on the other is en_us. That's why they dont join correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `en-us` to `en_us`, try below solution

```
SELECT Users.LanguageId
FROM Users
JOIN Locale ON Users.LanguageId = REPLACE(Locale.LanguageId,'-','_')
```

or better way is to fix data in your table:

```
update Locale
set LanguageId = REPLACE(LanguageId,'-','_')
```